# Error adding Alert Rule to Azure Cloud Service

Tags: powershell, azure, monitoring

I've created a script to add alert rules to several Azure resources (web apps, SQL databases, and cloud services). Everything works except for creating the cloud service alerts which returns an error:

> Add-AlertRule : ResourceProviderNotSupported: The resource provider
>   'Microsoft.ClassicCompute' is not supported.

This is the script I'm using to add the rule:

```
$cloudServices = Get-AzureResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup

Foreach ($cloudService in $cloudServices)
{
    # Cloud Service - CPU Percentage
    Add-AlertRule `
      -RuleType Metric `
      -Name "CPU Percentage (Cloud Service)" `
      -Location $cloudService.Location `
      -ResourceGroup $cloudService.ResourceGroupName `
      -Operator GreaterThan `
      -Threshold 75 `
      -WindowSize 01:00:00 `
      -ResourceId $cloudService.ResourceId `
      -MetricName "Percentage CPU" `
      -TimeAggregationOperator Average `
      -SendToServiceOwners
}
```

I've tried other using a different `ResourceType` parameter to target the role instead of the cloud service, but that doesn't work either.

Has anyone had any experience scripting these cloud service alerts successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Garrett sometime back I had created same kind of stuff without any issues. Please have a look on this link-

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/11/08/scripts-to-tools-automate-monitoring-alert-rules-in-microsoft-azure-with-powershell-and-the-azure-service-management-rest-api.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I saw your blog post earlier, but I was hoping to use the ResourceManager PowerShell module instead of calling the REST API. We're also not using PS 4.0, which it seems like your script requires.

With that being said, I tried tweaking the ResourceId based on what you were using in your script, but I still had the same error.

Comment: This answer does not contain the information that you would consider useful. Right now it only contains a link. Please update the answer with the relevant information.